# Google App Script. Move files that are older than 2 hours from last edit from One Shared Drive to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below code working nicely for the move process of any files in One shared drive to another. I am trying to amend the below to also add condition to check the last updated time stamp so that if the file is 2 hours or more from the last edit it will be moved.

Here is the below code that is working for the moving of the files from shared folder A to shared folder B.

```
function moveFiles(sourceDriveId, targetFolderId) { 
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var lastUpdate = scriptProperties.getProperty('lastUpdate');
if(lastUpdate == null) {
scriptProperties.setProperty('lastUpdate', new Date().getTime());
return;
}

var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
var sourceDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceDriveId);
var files = sourceDrive.getFiles();

 while(files.hasNext()){
 var file = files.next();
 if(file.getDateCreated().getTime() > lastUpdate) {
  file.makeCopy(file.getName(), targetFolder); 
  Drive.Files.remove(file.getId(), {supportsAllDrives: true});
 }
 }  
 scriptProperties.setProperty('lastUpdate', new Date().getTime());  
 }

 function test() {
  moveFiles("0AHJ7TY_Fdd1hUk9PVx", "0AEzW-YOJoXAEUk9PVx");
 }
```

====

I have seen other scripts delete files that are older than X amount of hours (or days) but not for copying files. I am hoping to amend the above code to include the condition checking if it is 2 or more hours old.

Have tried to adust the above 'move' code with adding condition based copy If older than 2 hours after last edit but have not been able to get it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the files that are over 2 hours from the last modified date.
- You want to move those files using `file.makeCopy(file.getName(), targetFolder)` and `Drive.Files.remove(file.getId(), {supportsAllDrives: true})`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `moveFiles` is modified. In this case, `getLastUpdated()` is used.

```js
function moveFiles(sourceDriveId, targetFolderId) {
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  var sourceDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceDriveId);
  var files = sourceDrive.getFiles();
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var diff = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 2 hour. This is from your question.
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getLastUpdated().getTime() + diff < now) {
      console.log(file.getName()); // You can see the filenames in the log.
      file.makeCopy(file.getName(), targetFolder);
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true });
    }
  }
}
```

- When this modified script is run, I thought that the above goal might be able to be achieved.

#### Reference:

- [getLastUpdated() of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getlastupdated)

Comment: That is perfect. Many thanks. Just been testing this script in a few different scenarios with  mixed folders and it works as planned.

Comment: @Exeter Trees About `That is perfect. Many thanks. Just been testing this script in a few different scenarios with mixed folders and it works as planned.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question on a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer